# Concatenate archive boost serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

Suppose I want to serialize two integers. The serialization is performed by two separated functions. I'd like to concatenate the two archives to get only one. I'm trying to do it through the boost::archive::xml_oarchive, but what I've it's only a two separated xmls.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just share the archive between the functions.

Not:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;

void foo() {
     boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(std::cout);
     oa << a;
}
void bar() {
     boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(std::cout);
     oa << b;
}
```

But:

```
void foo(boost::archive::xml_oarchive& oa) {
     oa << a;
}
void bar(boost::archive::xml_oarchive& oa) {
     oa << b;
}
```

Then you can:

```
void foobar() {
     boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(std::cout);
     foo(oa);
     bar(oa);
}
```